# How to select data by timestamp not older than ... (timestamp must be read on server side)

Tags: c#, mongodb, mongodb-query

I need to select a document respectively I have to check existence using a condition. In SQL I should write following query:

```sql
SELECT * 
FROM dummy
WHERE
  timestamp >= CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 300
```

Expression `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - 300` should be read as "current server timestamp minus 5 minutes" regardless used SQL server (the syntax differs).

To achieve that I need to use **server timestamp**. The reason is obvious - I can't trust client's date/time settings.

I can read current server timestamp from client and use it again to construct a filter, but more comfortable and serious is to construct a filter which is able to access server timestamp directly.

I'm currently using this filter:

```
FilterDefinition<BsonDocument> filter = new BsonDocument()
{
    { "$or", new BsonArray()
    {
        new BsonDocument() { { "processing_started", new BsonDocument() { { "$exists", false } } } },
        new BsonDocument() { { "processing_started", BsonNull.Value } },
        new BsonDocument()
        {
            { "$and", new BsonArray()
            {
                new BsonDocument() { { "processing_status", "started" } },
                new BsonDocument() { { "processing_started", new BsonDocument() { { "$lte", new BsonDocument() { { "$subtract", new BsonArray() { "new Date()", ProcessingTimeout * 1000 } } } } } } }
            }
            }
        }
    }
    }
};
```

but I'm not sure if that `"new Date()"` expression is evaluated on server side or on client.

Answer (score -1):

The 300 you are taking off is days, 1 = 1 day. The easiest way of doing this is probably just to divide the minutes by 24 then 60.

(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP - (5.0/24.0/60.0))

Yes though to your comment about server time. if it's an application running on the client's machine, it will be the client time, but if the code is SQL, it will be the server time.

Comment: Filter is run inside client application therefore I get a client's time. Is there any way how to construct a filter which will access server time directly?

Comment: The SQL will be the server time. As stated in my comment. The check you are doing using SQL will be server time, so you are doing it the correct way by using SQL to work it out. There wont be a way to check inside your client's application though, aside from writing some kind of service for this, but using the SQL will be fine to get the server time.

Comment: If you need to get the server time into your app though, you could just call the SQL "select CURRENT_TIMESTAMP"

Comment: But I'm asking how to do similar thing (as in SQL above) in MongoDB's find statement.

Comment: I thought you were just mentioning the query issues, as there was no mention of mongo db anywhere in your question.